# Parameter disapearing in inherit function

Tags: c++, parameters

I have 1 parent class("Area") and some son classes("circle", "polygon", etc.).
one of the virtual inherited functions behave in a very weird way - it's input parameter disappears on the run (seen on debugging mode). it makes some memory weird error..
do you have any idea?(let's assume Segment class is working well)

```
class Point {
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(){};
    Point(int xP, int yP):x(xP), y(yP){}
};


class Area {
public:
    virtual ~Area() {
    }
    virtual bool contains(const Point& p1) const=0;
};


class Circle: public Area {
    double radius;
    Point center;
public:
    ~Circle() {}
    Circle(double radiusP, Point centerP) :
            radius(radiusP), center(centerP) {}
    bool contains(const Point& p1) const;
};
```

and the definition of the function (contains):

```
bool Circle::contains(const Point& p1) const {
    return Segment(center, p1).getLength() < radius;
}
```

Comment: Could you give us the error too?

Comment: 1. Need more details on the error 2. Post the code that invokes the "contains" method

Comment: When you say disappearing do you mean its value is not visible in your debugger, or are you getting an explicit memory error notification?

Comment: [SSCCE, please](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

P1 is a reference. If p1 got deleted, or was a temporary that went out of scope while contains was running you'd get a memory error.

@lezebulon An example of a temporary going out of scope:

```
Point& getPoint()
{
    Point p;
    return p;
}

void doStuff()
{
    Point& p = getPoint(); // p is already bad... but will probably still work.
    area->contains( p ); // oops stack overwritten, p obliterated
}
```

Comment: the temporary can't run out of scope while the method is executed though

Comment: It would have been a temporary in another function that got wiped out after the next call.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: thank you, but my problem was some sort of mess with the copy c'tors.